Flutter App Shows Grey Screen in APK Build, Works Fine on Emulator (After Update)
I'm encountering a strange issue with my Flutter app that has me stumped. Here's the situation:

The app works perfectly fine in the emulator (both debug and release modes).
When I build the APK or test on iOS through TestFlight, some screens are completely grey.

What I've Tried:
I searched Stack Overflow and tried several suggestions:

Removed Expanded widgets that might cause layout issues.
Cleared app cache and reinstalled with new build after performing flutter clean.
Verified that there are no errors in the logs using flutter build apk --release -v.
Commanded out parts of the code, and re-enabled them line by line to isolate the issue.

Finally, I traced the issue to hard-coded data in the controller section of my app. When I removed the variables and directly passed the data (e.g., instead of using a variable to store the data), the grey screen issue disappeared in the APK build.
Important Points:

No errors in the verbose logs.
The same code works perfectly fine on the emulator but produces grey screens in the APK build.
This issue only surfaced after I updated Flutter to the latest version.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue, especially after a Flutter update? Is there something I should be aware of in the way hard-coded data is handled in production builds, compared to how it's processed in the emulator?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

please try clearing cache and data from setting -> app section. If it solves you need to disable allowbackup.

I have done that too. Jayant

Do you have WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() in your main function?

Yes, I have it already @Reza

Please try to enable Firebase Crashlytics or any other error loggers to catch it, it will make your life easier

try running flutter run --release . It will run on the release mode and you can fix grey screen .

I have already tried all these methods.

you will not find an exact answer here. you have an error/crash in your release build. to understand what the reason is you need to get data from this release application. naturally, you will not see anything in the logs. you write something about the controller and data-at least this information and what is happening there, you need to get. this can be done in different ways. the simplest method in the forehead is to make a log page directly in the application place logs in the controller and methods of working with this data.of cours,it is necessary to provide the ability to get this screen

The information you provided is kinda insufficient, so first, I suggest edit your question with detailed information.
Second, this problem seems to be related to flutter's release build optimizations like Tree-Shaking and Obfuscation. When you're building a release version, flutter will alter variables that consider them as "unused".
so, I suggest

Disable flutters release build optimizations.
Protect your variables. If you are hardcoding data through variables, try using const

Also make sure that you dont missed any permission in "main" manifest file.

Try Flutter run --release and check where you're getting crash.

flutter build apk --split-per-abi
